# How to Get the current Time in "29 Aug 2018 3:12:32 PM IST" format using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the current IST Time using javascript in the below format:
29 Aug 2018 3:12:32 PM IST

I tried:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var hour = today.getTime();
var hr = today.getHours();
var min = today.getMinutes();
var sec = today.getSeconds();
if(dd<10) {
 dd = '0'+dd
 } if(mm<10) {
mm = '0'+mm
} 
today = dd + " " + mm + " " + yyyy + " " + hr +" "+ min + " " + sec;

window.alert(today); OR Print(today);

  Output->
  29 08 2018 16 52 5
  But i need it in 29 Aug 2018 3:12:32 PM IST format
```

Is it possible to get in the above format?

Comment: Can you please use the same time in your examples?

Comment: There are some ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date